# Get control of a Minimized form

Tags: c#, forms

I have three forms, the main, the second one and the last which is opened by the second one using *ShowDialog*().

**If I minimize the last form, I go back to the first form, and in turn a button is activated to return to the last form. If I click this button, I can see the last form but I can't use it, I can only see it**.

How can I get the control of this form?

**Code of Minimize of the last form**:

```
 private void button_minimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.Hide();
    Principal fom = new Principal(true, this);
    fom.ShowDialog();
 }
```

**Code of first form to open again the last form**:

```
 private void bt_galvCh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    formMinimizadoGalv.Activate();
    formMinimizadoGalv.BringToFront();
    formMinimizadoGalv.Focus();
    formMinimizadoGalv.Show();
 }
```

This is the last form, I can see it with this code but I can use the green button:

[Picture of the last form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7D12.png)

Comment: ShowDialog blocks access to 2nd form. Try to use Show(), but that might cause 2 forms appear if you click button again (unless it is singleton).

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis but if I use form, how can I detect when the button of the second form is clicked?

Comment: If 2nd form is dialog - use dialog result to see if ok or cancel was pressed.

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis I tried but if I click the button of the last form, it is not doing nothing.